# Concatenate many files into one file without the header

Tags: bash, unix

I have three csv files (with the same name, e.g. `A_bestInd.csv`) that are located in different subfolders. I want to copy all of them into one file (e.g. `All_A_bestInd.csv`). To do that, I did the following:

```
{ find . -type f -name A_bestInd.csv -exec cat '{}' \; ; } >> All_A_bestInd.csv
```

The result of this command is the following:

```
Class   Conf        1   2   3   4 //header of file1
A       Reduction   5   1   2   1
A       Reduction   1   8   1   10
Class   Conf        1   2   3   4 //header of file2
A       No_red      2   1   3   2
A       No_red      3   6   1   9
Class   Conf        1   2   3   4 //header of file3
A       Reduction   5   5   8   9
A       Reduction   7   2   1   11
```

As you can see, the issue is the header of each file is copied. How can I change my command to keep only one header and avoid the rest?

Answer (score 2):

Use `tail +2` to trim the headers from all the files.

```
find . -type f -name A_bestInd.csv -exec tail +2 {} \; >> All_A_bestInd.csv
```

To keep just one header you could combine it with `head -1`.

```
{ find . -type f -name A_bestInd.csv -exec head -1 {} \; -quit
  find . -type f -name A_bestInd.csv -exec tail +2 {} \; } >> All_A_bestInd.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions with `tail +2` and `awk`, but it seems to me the classic way to print all but the first line of a file is sed: `sed -e 1d`.  So:

```
find . -type f -name A_bestInd.csv -exec sed -e 1d '{}' \; >> All_A_bestInd.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to filter out header lines from all files but the first (except you have thousands of them):

```
find . -type f -name 'A_bestInd.csv' -exec awk 'NR==1 || FNR>1' {} + > 'All_A_bestInd.csv'
```

`NR==1 || FNR>1` means; if the **number of current line from the start of input is 1**, or, the **number of current line from the start of current file is greater than 1**, print current line.

---

```
$ cat A_bestInd.csv 
Class   Conf        1   2   3   4 //header of file3
A       Reduction   5   5   8   9
A       Reduction   7   2   1   11
$ 
$ cat foo/A_bestInd.csv 
Class   Conf        1   2   3   4 //header of file1
A       Reduction   5   1   2   1
A       Reduction   1   8   1   10
$ 
$ cat bar/A_bestInd.csv 
Class   Conf        1   2   3   4 //header of file2
A       No_red      2   1   3   2
A       No_red      3   6   1   9
$ 
$ find . -type f -name 'A_bestInd.csv' -exec awk 'NR==1 || FNR>1' {} + > 'All_A_bestInd.csv'
$
$ cat All_A_bestInd.csv 
Class   Conf        1   2   3   4 //header of file1
A       Reduction   5   1   2   1
A       Reduction   1   8   1   10
A       Reduction   5   5   8   9
A       Reduction   7   2   1   11
A       No_red      2   1   3   2
A       No_red      3   6   1   9
```